# SQL - If input string is empty return all rows , otherwise try to match

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have table **matches** with these columns:

```
|sport|region|country|league
```

1. If the input string for **sport** is empty I want to return everything and don't bother with matching region, country etc.
2. If **sport** is not empty then find rows with matched sports and proceed to **region** and do the same thing.

Is this possible to do in SQL? I know I can filter this out in PHP and then run different SQL queries.

Comment: try stored procedures. pass the parameters an check there if you want to put your business logic in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
WHERE (sport_param IS NULL OR sport_column = sport_param)
```

You might want to use the `LIKE` operator or consider case-insensitive checking instead of simply comparing the exact sport.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx)
... you can basically make an if statement in SQL to match whether sport is empty or not and depending on that execute two different queries.